# How did Strange know that Mordo had gone full psychopath?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, when talking about Mordo, Dr. Stephen Strange says:

> STRANGE: And then he snapped and dedicated his life to trying to kill me.
> <sup>*Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*</sup>

How does Strange know this?

- Mordo left Strange in 2016, with the words "the bill comes due" or something similar, but does not reveal to Wong or Strange that he believes the sorcerers must be killed, only that he himself will forsake magic.
- In an after-credits scene of *Doctor Strange* (2016), Mordo steals the power of Jonathan Pangborn, but (as far as I can tell) *discreetly*.
- In 2017, things seem to be going normally for Strange, although he does have to deal with Thor, Loki, and Odin briefly.
- In 2018, Thanos snapped away half the population ("The Blip"), *including* Dr. Strange.
- in 2023, the Avengers revived everyone who had been snapped away, Dr. Strange included.
- *Multiverse of Madness* takes place sometime around late 2024.

This does give some room during which Strange could have discovered this, for example between 2016 and 2018, or between early 2023 and late 2024.

When and how did Strange discover Mordo's vendetta against sorcerers? Was that particular plot thread resolved somewhere I didn't notice?

Comment: I'd heard that this showed up in early versions of the script, but apparently that was [his death at the beginning of the film at the hands of the villain](https://www.cbr.com/doctor-strange-2-scarlet-witch-kill-mordo-mcu/) (spoilers behind link).

Comment: We aren’t shown most of what goes on in the MCU, presumably during the intervening years Strange and the Sorcerers have had run ins with Mordo.

Comment: Or, you know, heard it from someone else. Wong seems like a bit of a gossip.